# read OS files into numpy array in the order that is in the computer

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a folder with several files, and I want to upload them to spyder, as a numpy array. 
I can read, but the order is not right, so I don't know each file is it.

this is my code:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import pandas as pd
import importlib.util


cur_dir = 'C:/Users/..'
os.chdir(cur_dir)



dpred = []
dobs = []
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if file.endswith('dpred.npy'):
        dpred.append(np.load(file))
    elif file.endswith('dobs.txt'):
        dobs.append(np.loadtxt(file))
```

this is my folder:
[image: my folder]

and this is what I get in spyder:
[image: numpy ndarray spyder]
My problem is that my 1dobs that was in my folder is not the element 0 in this numpy array, but is it the number 6. So, is not reading in order. How can I fixe that? Tha same happens to my dpred.npy files...

Comment: You may use the `glob` function from `glob` package to get a list of files that you can sort in a specific order.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the glob function:

```
from glob import glob
files = glob(folder + '*.txt')
files

['10dobs.txt',
 '11dobs.txt',
 '12dobs.txt',
 '13dobs.txt',
 '1dobs.txt',
 '2dobs.txt',
 '3dobs.txt',
 '4dobs.txt',
 '5dobs.txt',
 '6dobs.txt',
 '7dobs.txt',
 '8dobs.txt',
 '9dobs.txt']
```

The files list can be sorted in the order you need it. Here it is a character ordering. You need a numeric ordering:

```py
import re
import numpy as np

a = np.array([int(re.search('(\d+)dobs.txt', f).group(1)) for f in files])
np_files = np.array(files)

# rearrange the numpy string array using the index of the numerically 
# sorted transformed list
np_files[np.argsort(a)]

array(['1dobs.txt', '2dobs.txt', '3dobs.txt', '4dobs.txt', '5dobs.txt',
       '6dobs.txt', '7dobs.txt', '8dobs.txt', '9dobs.txt', '10dobs.txt',
       '11dobs.txt', '12dobs.txt', '13dobs.txt'], dtype='<U10')
```

Comment: I tried that but still not ordering, my code now was: it shows everything that start with 1 firs, like 10,11,15,1,2,8,9 ... and I would like to have ordered like, 1,2,9,10,11,15

Comment: It is a text ordering. You want the numeric ordering from the beginning of the file name. You may split the file name before ordering. I ll update my answer later today.